# app_template and project_template : custom variables

Tags: django

When starting projects or apps with custom app_template or project_template, is there a way to pass custom variable to the executable to use them in the -tpl files?

For instance I'd like to start my projects directly with channels settings and I'd like to automatically the redis server.

"No, there is no reasonnably simple way to achieve this" may also be a valid answer.